# Updated date field is not updated

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have defined this schema

```
var docSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdAt',updatedAt:'updatedAt' }, collection : 'docs', discriminatorKey : '_type' });
```

I update the documents using this route

```
router.post('/:id', auth, function(req,res,next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    docA.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err)
            res.json(err);
        else if(doc==null)
            res.status(404).send({
                message: "Document not found"
            });
        else
            res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

I noticed `updatedAt` is not updated when I save some edits to the documents.
Besides this problem, thinking about it, it could be helpful to keep this data in form of array of updated date like:

```
updatedAt : [
"2016-10-25T12:52:44.967Z",
"2016-11-10T12:52:44.967Z",
"2016-12-01T12:52:44.967Z"
]
```

**SOLUTION(?)**:According to @chridam suggestions, my current workaround to keep an array of update Dates is:

```
docSchema.pre(`findOneAndUpdate`, function(next) {
if(!this._update.updateHistory) {
    console.log("findOneAndUpdate hook: updateHistory not present")
    this._update.updateHistory=[];
}
this._update.updateHistory.push(new Date);

return next();
});
docSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if(!this.updateHistory) {
        console.log("Save hook: updateHistory not present")
        this.updateHistory=[];
    }
    this.updateHistory.push(new Date);
next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, please refer to the original thread on the plugin [here](https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp/issues/13#issuecomment-45144198), where [dunnkers](https://github.com/dunnkers) [commented](https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp/issues/13#issuecomment-45144198):

> It's actually impossible to hook middleware onto update,
>   `findByIdAndUpdate`, `findOneAndUpdate`, `findOneAndRemove` and
>   `findByIdAndRemove` in Mongoose at the moment.
>
> This means that no plugin is actually run when using any of these
>   functions.
>
> Check out the [notes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) section in the Mongoose documentation for
>   middleware. Issue [Automattic/mongoose#964](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964) also describes this.

As a suggested workaround, factoring in your schema changes:

```
var docSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "name": { "type": String, "required": true },
    "updateHistory": [Date]
}, { 
    "timestamps": { 
        "createdAt": 'createdAt',
        "updatedAt": 'updatedAt' 
    }, 
    "collection" : 'docs', 
    "discriminatorKey": '_type' 
});

router.post('/:id', auth, function(req,res,next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    docA.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err)
            res.json(err);
        else if(doc==null)
            res.status(404).send({
                message: "Document not found"
            });
        else {
            doc.updateHistory.push(new Date());
            doc.save().then(function(doc){
                res.json(doc);
            }, function(err) {
                // want to handle errors here
            })
        }            
    });
});
```

---

Another approach would be to attach a hook to the schema:

```
docSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", function() {
    this.updatedAt = Date.now();
});
```

Comment: As you can see I use a discriminatorKey, so I have several inherited models to `doc`: `docA`,`docB`,`docC`,`docD`..
Maybe a pre save hook would provide the same workaround? It should handles the creation and the edits however.. I would avoid to pach tons of routes

Comment: Yes, a pre-update hook sounds like the ideal route for you. Check updated answer.

Comment: check for `this._update.updateHistory` it looks like it works, but I'm not totally sure if it's the right thing to check